# How do I ask the user to enable the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions

Android 11 is [more restrictive](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files) than older versions when providing access to user files.

The goal is to improve security, and that is ok, but it breaks some apps.

To fix that, we can add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to the app manifest. That allows the user to go to the app settings and turn on the option (allow management of all files):

[image]

But this is not enough by itself, as users won't do that if they are not asked for it. They will only see an app that does not work.

At this moment, there is literally [no mention](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/search?q=MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) to this particular permission on the React Native repository.

Is there any solution to this? We should be able to check whether that permission has been given so we can act accordingly, and we should be able to ask the user to grant the permission.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/manage-external-storage

```
// check if can manage
checkManagePermission().then((isManagePermitted) => {
  console.log(isManagePermitted);
});

// request rights to manage
requestManagePermission().then((isManagePermitted) => {
  console.log(isManagePermitted);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have overall storage access then you need to add the following code in your `MainActivity.kt`

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.Settings

 class MainActivity : ReactActivity() {
   ....

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R && 
!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
       val intent = 
   Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)
       val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
       intent.data = uri
       startActivity(intent)
     }
   }
 }
```

After adding this code you need to restart the server and now you are able to access all the files in external storage

It will ask to manage all files once if not given then ask again ✅Solved

AndroidManifest.xml =>

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

It will automatically ask the user to give permission so no need to add the react native code to do that. Also it can able to read inside the hidden folders.